# Effect of random matrices on the product of two perpendicular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, random-matrices

For two non-square perpendicular matrices $X$ and $Y$ (i.e., $X^T Y = 0$), what happens when we bring a random matrix $A \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ (with i.i.d. elements) to the inner product, as follows?

$X^T (A^T A) Y = \text{?}$

Can we say anything about this multiplication?

Comment: Ever since some time in the 19th century, it has been standard to use the term "orthogonal matrix" to refer to a square matrix whose inverse is its transpose. So your terminology is somewhat non-standard. $\qquad$

Comment: good point, my point is that X and Y are orthogonal two each other (as clarified in the braces), and not that they are orthogonal themselves.

Comment: "perpendicular matrices"?

Comment: yeah, good suggestion, I made that change.

Comment: the reality is for two matrices to be orthogonal or perpendicular to *each other* means they evaluate to $0 \in \mathbb F$ for some bilinear (or hermitian) form.  Over reals, the standard choice / interpretation is $\text{trace}\big( X^T Y\big) = 0$  **not**  $ X^T Y = \mathbf 0$ as the latter is not a form.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious observations:

(a)
$$<X^T A^T A Y> = X^T <A^T A> Y = X^T I Y = 0$$ where $<\cdots>$ means the expectation.

(b)

$$A^T A$$ is a matrix composed of products of i.i.d Gaussian variables, so the matrix $$M = X^T A^T A Y$$is a matrix composed of linear combinations of these products.

**As for deeper results**, I think that if you consider the generating function $$<e^{\lambda M}>$$ you can get quite a lot of information. This computation seems doable because the distribution is a gaussian and the exponential is quadratic in these variables and the integral will converge, at least if $\lambda<0$.  that is:
$$<e^{\lambda M}>=\int dA_{11}\cdots\int dA_{nn}e^{\lambda X^T A^T A Y-{1\over 2\sigma^2}\sum_{ab}A^2_{ab}}$$
At this point it becomes an exercise in Gaussian integrals which I leave as an "excercise for the reader". Whether that gives you enough information on the distribution is up to you, but in principle, it seems that generating functions are the way to proceed.